# Как сохранить русские названия папок при копировании на ftp?

Tags: ftp, java

Для связи с ftp сервером использую org.apache.commons.net.ftp библиотеку. Все работает, претензий никаких. Но на локальной машине встречаются файлы и папки вида qweУЙ12.22.12, то есть содержащие в себе русские буквы. Естественно моя программа копирует имена этих папок и файлов на ftp сервер неверно (заменяет русские буквы на ??). Как я могу копировать каталоги, содержащие русские буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил просто... Почему-то на всех фтп что я видел внутренняя кодировка koi8-r поэтому при считывании файлов я конвертировал все в utf-8 так как использовал java. А когда грузил на фтп конвертировал в koi8-r.

Answer (score 4):

Надо посмотреть в каком виде читает ваш клиент русские имена файлов (кодировка Win-1251?)из локальной машины. По идее (если все настроено правильно) она должна транслировать их нормально - выведите их имена в лог и сразу увидите имена правильные или нет.

Далее надо посмотреть/получить кодировку оси на удаленной машине (КОИ-8/UTF-8?). Если ваша библиотека не обеспечивает автоматом кодировку - то надо перекодировать полученные из локальной машины имена в кодировку удаленного сервера.

В общем смысл в том, чтобы передавать на удаленную машину правильные имена.

Comment: программа плнруется должна работать под linux ubuntu (utf-8) и windows XP (там не знаю какая кодировка). Как узнать кодировку на удаленной машине? Она зависит только от ОС? Или еще и от настроек сервера? На удаленной машине стоит windows server 2003

Answer (score 2):

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.setControlEncoding("CP1251");
ftpClient.connect(server, port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не создавал вообще каталоги с кириллицей, пока не добавил кодировку. Главное установить кодировку до соединения с сервером.

```
val ftpClient = FTPClient()
ftpClient.controlEncoding = "Windows-1251"
ftpClient.connect(host, port)
```

Comment: Это фактически совпадает с кодом в ответе от HAPCOM